# Unbalanced groups in repeated measures anova

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics, unbalanced-classes

I am analysing metabolomics data (~1,000 measurements) across 30 samples from 10 subjects.

The samples are from 2 treatments groups of 5 subjects from whom 3 muscle samples were taken from 3 locations (2 from top and bottom of one muscle (A) and the other from a different muscle B).
The initial hypothesis was that the treatment*muscle location effect on metabolite levels. This was to be tested using a repeated measures two-way anova.

However, initial analysis shows that the 2 samples from muscle A differ minimally compared to difference between A vs B. So I am worried in an ANOVA using all 3 locations the two samples from muscle A would function as replicates and this may lead to over estimation of significance of location effect.

I was wondering if my concerns are correct and whether I should just take average from the samples from A and then go with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you started with a particular hypothesis and an associated analysis approach, it's usually not a good idea to change them based on a first look at the data.

Your repeated-measures ANOVAs will provide estimates of differences between the two A-muscle locations and of each A-muscle location versus the B muscle. It's possible that the complete analysis will show some metabolites for which the A-muscle location does matter in a practically and statistically significant way. Don't throw away that possibility at the start by throwing away the top vs. bottom A-muscle site information.

> I was wondering ... whether I should just take average from the samples from A and then go with that.

That is *forcing* the A samples to "function like replicates" in a way that separate analysis of the locations wouldn't do. It would seem more likely to over-estimate the "significance of location effect" than continuing with your original analysis approach.

Starting with averages between 2 A-muscle locations will tend to average out technical measurement errors from the A muscle in a way that wouldn't be done for the B muscle. Keeping the A-muscle locations separate in the initial analysis doesn't. If you start with your planned separate analysis of the A-muscle locations you can still choose to compare the average A-muscle values against the B-muscle values in a contrast.